# How do I get Chrome to open M3U *outside* the browser

Tags: google-chrome, mime-types, m3u

I'm running Chrome on Windows 7.  I have WinAmp as my MP3 player, and it is also associated with M3U files in the operating system.  When I double-click an M3U file in Windows explorer, WinAmp opens it.

However, in Chrome, when clicking on a link that points to a .M3U file, instead of opening the M3U file in WinAmp, Chrome handles it right there in the browser.

What I've tried:
Right-click the M3U link, and download it.  Then right-click on the downloaded file name at the bottom of the Chrome window, and select Always Open files of this type.

Once downloaded, I can click the file in the Downloads bar, and it will open with WinAmp then.  But it would be great not to have to download first and then click.

Thanks!
Sandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Chrome plugin handling it instead of having Chrome download it.

`Settings>Advanced>Content Settings>Disable Individual Plugins...`

And then disable or modify whichever one is handling `m3u` files.

If it still doesn't work, there may be a silver shield icon displayed up in on the right side of the address/search bar, next to the bookmark star:

[image]

I encountered that when running on my self-signed SSL home server and had to enable the loading of the "unsafe script".

Comment: Thank you Nick, I think the first suggestion you gave is what I eventually used to fix the problem after a bunch of Googling, though it was a long time ago now, and I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Sure thing. The second problem is really just related to my site being SSL, and the M3U originating from/containing non-SSL URLs.